# looking for a screen recorder for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, screen

looking for a screen recorder for 16.04 that can record my screen be able to pause and resume record ingame audio and audio from other things like discord for when im playing with my friends does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: You should ask this at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah. Take a look at Kazam. I think  it supports pausing through the taskbar icon.